# celery: call a task after all subtasks of all subtasks have run

Tags: python, celery

I have two main tasks: **main_A** and **main_B**.

extract_new spawns a large number of **sub** tasks, which itself spawns the **subsub1** and **subsub2** tasks.

I want to run **main_B** after all **subsubA** and **subsubB** tasks have run. In this diagram, tasks depend on the tasks above:

```
                  main_A
                  /    \
                 /      \
                /        \
               /          \
              sub          sub
              /\           / \
             /  \         /   \
          sub1   sub2    sub1  sub2
            \     |      /      /
             \    |     /      /
              \   |    /      /
               \  |   /      /

                  main_B
```

How can I do that? If I set **main_B** as the callback for **main_A**, it will be run juste after **main_A** has spawned the **sub** tasks. If I run **sub** tasks as a chord with **main_B** as a callback, **main_B** will be run before the **subsub1** and **subsub2** have finished.

Both of those are not options, since main_B depends on data created by the **sub**, **subsub1** and **subsub2** tasks.

Comment: I think the solution is http://stackoverflow.com/a/16897241/1200503, since the question looks a lot like mine. However, having looked at the linked PR, I can't see how that could be used for my problem...

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use `AsyncResult.collect()` to manage this - see [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.collect)

```
@app.task
def runner(x, y, z):
    result = main_a.apply_async((x, y,z))
    result.collect()

    main_B.apply_async()
```

you'll need to check for errors etc also

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help me. The idea is that result.collect() would block until all main_A's subtasks have run?

Answer (score 1):

If you require full non-blocking behaviour then you can refactor your code so that instead of spawning sub-tasks your tasks simply build a canvas object and pass it back up the call chain

```
my_chain = mainA.s((params,...)) | mainA_subtasks.s(params) | main_B(params)

@app.task
def mainA(params):
    # in here put the main work done by mainA

def mainA_subtasks(params):

    my_group = []
    for i in some_loop():
        tasks = get_sub_tasks(params, i)
        my_group.extend(tasks)

    return group(my_group)

# and so on
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks good. However, if I return a group in mainA_substasks, main_B will receive the group as an argument. What should be changed for the group to be run, and its result sent to main_B?

Comment: To clarify, I want the chain do the same as: chord(subtasks, link=main_B.s(params)), with subtasks the subtasks returned by mainA_subtasks.