# Use .replace method with Celery sub-tasks

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to solve a problem in celery:

- I have one task that queries an API for ids, and then starts a sub-task for each of these.
- I do not know, ahead of time, what the ids are, or how many there are.
- For each id, I go through a big calculation that then dumps some data into a database.
- After *all* the sub-tasks are complete, I want to run a summary function (export DB results to an Excel format).
- Ideally, I do not want to block my main worker querying the status of the sub-tasks (Celery gets angry if you try this.)

This question looks very similar (if not identical?): [Celery: Callback after task hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737127/celery-callback-after-task-hierarchy)

So using the "solution" (which is a link to [this discussion](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/817), I tried the following test script:

```
# test.py
from celery import Celery, chord
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

app = Celery('test', backend='redis://localhost:45000/10?new_join=1', broker='redis://localhost:45000/11')
app.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@app.task(bind=True)
def get_one(self):
    print('hello world')
    self.replace(get_two.s())
    return 1


@app.task
def get_two():
    print('Returning two')
    return 2


@app.task
def sum_all(data):
    print('Logging data')
    logger.error(data)
    return sum(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Running test')
    x = chord(get_one.s() for i in range(3))
    body = sum_all.s()
    result = x(body)

    print(result.get())
    print('Finished w/ test')
```

It doesn't work for me. I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'get_one' object has no attribute 'replace'

Note that I *do* have new_join=1 in my backend URL, though not the broker. If I put it there, I get an error:

> TypeError: _init_params() got an unexpected keyword argument 'new_join'

What am I doing wrong? I'm using the Python 3.4.3 and the following packages:

```
amqp==1.4.6
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.20
celery==3.1.18
kombu==3.0.26
pytz==2015.4
redis==2.10.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task.replace method will be added in Celery 3.2: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/master/whatsnew-3.2.html#task-replace (that changelog entry is misleading, because it suggests that Task.replace existed before and has been changed.)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Yes, I had read the changelogs, so figured it was in 3.1. I also did a search through source and thought it was there.